# Exporting gridview to excel giving empty excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I'm exporting a gridview to excel sheet on a button click event but the exported excel sheet is displaying only below information

[image]

Instead of the gridview data. Below if the code inside the export button click

```
    private void ExportGridView(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            //To Export all pages
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

            //style to format numbers to string
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }
```

Also the code in the aspx for gridview is

```
   ......
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  Font-Size="10pt" AllowSorting="True" 
                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC"  AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">
          <%--      <Columns>
             ....................
     <td> <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExport" Text="Export to Excel" onclick="btnExport_Click" /></td>
    </tr>
     </table>
  </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Where you are binding GridView ? Can you share the complete code of codebehind? GridView datasourse binding.

Comment: Try commenting out the part where you first write to the response stream, i.e. `Response.Write(style);`  My theory is that since this is the first thing excel sees instead of a table tag, it doesn't render it as a table.  Also, I should point out that this really isn't the best way to do this.  Yes, you can output a gridview's rendering (an html table) to Excel, but this really doesn't behave consistently.  Look at NPOI for creating excel documents, or something similar.

Comment: @priya777 I got the issue fixed. One of the reason was binding the data in the export button click.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.I did not bind the gridview after settting allowpaging to false. Below is the full code:

```
 private void ExportGridView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        //To Export all pages
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        //GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Also, another change was in .aspx file in the page I set EnableEventValidation = "false"